# When is Jsession id created in Oracle ATG is it from JBOSS or ATG?

Tags: jboss, atg, oracle-commerce

I want to know exactly where the session is being created. In Oracle ATG we are facing a post redirection Issue from `CanonicalSessionHostnameServlet`. When requesting the site through the domain name `www.example.com/example?postSessionRedirect=www.exaple.com` this problem happens, when requesting the site through the ip, this works fine and there is no redirection. Any help regarding the issue might be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55783_02/Platform.11-2/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0710sessioninteractionoutline01.html) on this is extensive but to paraphrase the session is created by the application server under jboss:

> When a request comes in without a session ID in the cookie or in the URL, the application server creates a new session for the requested web application.
>
> When the **singleSessionIdPerUser value is true** (which it is in jboss), the application server uses the same session ID for all web applications, so lookup is not required. Note that the application server hands out the same session id, but **not** the same HttpSession object.

You can check this in dyn/admin under `/atg/dynamo/
servlet/sessiontracking/GenericSessionManager.singleSessionIdPerUser`

Information on how to share among multiple applications is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55783_02/Platform.11-2/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0710sharingsessioninformationamongor01.html).

It sounds like you might have a problem with your multisite configuration in the BCC.

Answer (score 0):

JSESSIONID is a cookie and this unique session ID is generated by the application server.